# Azure & Microsoft Graph: Access denied accessing inbox, using Client Secret

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

We tried to setup the simplest possible application for reading emails from a mailbox in our organization, using Microsoft Graph.
It's a background service so we used ClientSecretCredential as authentication strategy.
Here is the code:

```
var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential("xxx-tenantID","xxx-clientId","xxx-clientSecret");

var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(credentials, new string [] {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"});

var result = await graphServiceClient.Users["myaddress@mycompany.com"].MailFolders["Inbox"] .Messages.Request() .GetAsync();
```

It seems to login correctly but then it gets an access denied when tring to access the specific inbox:

```
Unhandled exception. Status Code: Forbidden
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ErrorAccessDenied
Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
```

I think we miss some authorization on the azure side; in particular, we can't find the place where the application is authorized to access that specific mail box (myaddress@mycompany.com).

#### Update:

When we give to the application the authorization showed below, it works.
Unfortunately this gives access to *all the mailboxes in the organization* and this is unacceptable since this app should only access the service mail box it was designed to manage.
The question now is how to limit the access to the only mailbox required.

Sorry for italian language in the screenshot, the highlighted text means "Adminisrator consent" and is the settig that made the application work.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you need to create/edit an `ApplicationAccessPolicy` in Azure: [auth-limit-mailbox-access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access)

Answer (score 1):

To summarize you want to use client credentials to access a single mailbox?

You can use this powershell command to create an access policy to restrict this application to a single mailbox or group of mailboxes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-applicationaccesspolicy

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline

New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AccessRight RestrictAccess -AppId <String[]> -PolicyScopeGroupId your.service@account.com
```

Comment: Yes; is powershell the only way to do this?

Comment: This powershell is changing stuff in the underlying Exchange server, I have not seen an other way to change these. But it’s a one-time action (I would create a group for this, create the policy for the group and add one or more accounts to the group)

Comment: Tomorrow morning (it's almost midnight here) I'll try it and se how it works. My sys admin is a bit baffled by the fact that a security architecture so complex and apparently sophisticated turns out to be a all-or-nothing access. Not only that but it also violates the principle of least-possible-privileges, starting with a grant-all privilege. So we thought we missed something, instead it seems to be just like that.

Comment: Application credentials are highly privileged… I think you must be glad they now have the possibility to limit the application access, this is something they implemented later then the client credentials.

Comment: We chose this solution because we are developing a service that obviously is unattended. In a previous attempt we used DeviceCodeCredential, using the user associated with that mailbox. It's easier but it asks for authentication each time. Do you think DeviceCodeCredential can be used while suppressing this authentication, for example caching the token somehow?

Comment: DeviceCodeCredentials is not meant for deamon applications, this is why there’re client credentials. Just create the application policy. That makes sure you never have to reauthenicate

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, and after giving that powershell command that apparently worked, i receive ErrorAccessDenied trying to access myaddress@mycompany.com. Maybe it requires to give all the permissions via azure admin then restrict them via powershell or maybe the command doesn't to exactly that, infact the help of New-ApplicationAccessPolicy, example 2, description parameter is ambiguous to this concern. Honestly the lack of comprehensive management tools and the possibility of security issues makes this technology not so appealing to me right now.